# How to set the time based on the date selected from the datetime picker?

Tags: php

I have an input field of date time picker.

And below that I have a drop down of time.

My need is when I select a date from the date time picker then it should query the database and populate the drop down from the database values.

How will I do this?

Comment: I did not try any thing because I have no idea how to do this?

Comment: It's hard to answer this without some more specific examples. What columns are in the database table that you're querying? What is the relationship between dates and times through the database? Can you show us the HTML/PHP you are using for the picker, the dropdown, and the database access?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chained Select Boxes jquery php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724087/chained-select-boxes-jquery-php)

Comment: You'll have to get the date from the page into PHP and return results,  so ajax is your best bet. JS libraries make ajax much easier, so check out jQuery or MooTools.

Answer (score 0):

So here are things you need to research into.

1) is this going to be an ajax call, or a post? After the drop down is selected. Ajax is more difficult because you need to know how to use Javascript. Since you answer the question u have no idea where to begin, I assume you don't know how to use jquery or ajax. You should research into jquery/ajax

2) How to make a DB connection and query the DB, and loop through to get results. Here is a good starting point: http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

Hopefully this will help you get started, without knowing more about your environment, kinda hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Write AJAX function at onchange event, for example you have something on your page

```
 <select id ="menu1"><select>


 function add_option(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "your_url/get_query.php",
        // you should type your selected date from calendar in data row
        data: "",
        success:function (page) {
           $("#menu1").html(page);
        }
    });
 }
```

in your get_query.php file you write query and prepare your data to adding in to dropdown menu

```
    //take data from DB
    $result = "<option id=\"".$your_data['id']."\">".$your_data['title']."</option>"
    return $result
```

On success it will add returned content to your dropdown menu