# Passing dropdown list value to another SELECT statement on same page

Tags: php, mysql, variables, drop-down-menu

Hi and thanks for looking at this with me. I am COMPLETELY new to using PHP to run MySQL select statements. That being said, I have managed to run a SELECT statement to populate a drop down list...and another SELECT statement to populate an HTML table. (this is for a roleplaying game)

But this is where3 I get stuck...

I would like for the dropdown selected value to be the "WHERE racename = " value in the second select statement that populates the table so that only one row is returned instead of all the data.

Here's the page: http://www.gamehermit.com/racechoice.php

Here's my code so far:

```
<?php 

// Make a MySQL Connection 

mysql_connect("localhost", "db_username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error()); 

$query="SELECT * FROM Races"; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
echo "<select name=racename>"; 
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
if ($nt[racename]==$_POST["racename"]) 
$selected="selected"; 
else 
$selected=""; 
echo "<option ".$selected."value=$nt[racename]>$nt[racename]</option>"; 
} 
echo "</select>"; 
echo "<br />"; 

// Get all the data from the "Race" table and create table 

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Races") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

echo "<table border='1'>"; 
echo "<tr> <th>Race Name</th> <th>Might Modifier</th> <th>Valor Modifier</th>         <th>Deftness 

Modifier</th> <th>Insight Modifier</th> <th>Dweomer Modifier</th> </tr>"; 

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )) { 
// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo $row['racename']; 
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['modmight']; 
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['modvalor']; 
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['moddeftness']; 
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['modinsight']; 
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['moddweomer']; 
echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 

?>
```

I hope this is simple...thanks so much :)

~ Jack

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chained Select Boxes jquery php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724087/chained-select-boxes-jquery-php)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so is to use **AJAX** so you don't need to pass variables and load a new page.

But here's how you can do it with the old-fashioned way:

assume you will be having only one page and you will pass the selected value to the same page (a page reload is required)

so let's say your page is game.php

you need to include in this page a "jump menu" with a submit button to be pressed after the user selects something from the list

in the header of your page you need to check if the button was pressed using the

```
if(isset($_POST['button_name'])) {

// button pressed.. perform next step and select your new data to fill the table

} else {
// nothing pressed and nothing to be performed load the page normally
}
```

inside the "true" of the "if" you need here to get the passed variable from the list for example

```
$var = $_POST['list_name'];
```

so now you have the second variable to select the required data to fill the table.

a complete code should look something similar to the following, game.php:

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['go_button'])){ //option not selected display list to choose from
// Make a MySQL Connection 

mysql_connect("localhost", "db_username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error()); 

$query="SELECT * FROM Races"; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
$num = mysql_numrows($result);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_jumpMenuGo(objId,targ,restore){ //v9.0
  var selObj = null;  with (document) { 
  if (getElementById) selObj = getElementById(objId);
  if (selObj) eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
  if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0; }
}
</script>

<form name="form" id="form" action="game.php" method="post">
  <select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu">
  <?php $i=0; while($i<$num) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo mysql_result($result,$i,'racename_field_value'); ?>"><?php echo mysql_result($result,$i,'racename'); ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
  <input type="button" name="go_button" id= "go_button" value="Go" onClick="MM_jumpMenuGo('jumpMenu','parent',0)">
</form>

<?php
echo "<br />"; 
} else { //option selected to get the variable and use it to select data from DB

$var= $_POST['jumpMenu'];

// Get all the data from the "Race" table and create table 

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Races WHERE racename='$var'") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

echo "<table border='1'>"; 
echo "<tr> <th>Race Name</th> <th>Might Modifier</th> <th>Valor Modifier</th>         <th>Deftness 

Modifier</th> <th>Insight Modifier</th> <th>Dweomer Modifier</th> </tr>"; 

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )) { 
// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo $row['racename']; 
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['modmight']; 
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['modvalor']; 
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['moddeftness']; 
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['modinsight']; 
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['moddweomer']; 
echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 
}
?>
```

I modified your code and added something to get you start with, excuse me if there was any error when trying to load the page i wrote it without trying it

good luck!